# 3NF Normalization Algorithm Step: Relation with SuperKey

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf

I was wondering about the last step of the 3NF normalization algorithm where it states:

> 4) If none of the relations obtained in previous steps contains a superkey of R, then add a new relation whose schema is a key for R.

My specific question is, what happens with the semantic of that relation? Why have only one relation and not many single-attribute relations (one for each attribute of the key)?

I found that in some examples that extra relation makes sense, but in others it seems to "mix" attributes that aren't related...

Comment: If you have a component for each attribute of a CK, when you join them you get all possible tuples from all possible combinations of values for each attribute. Usually only some of those tuples appear in the relation--the ones that are in the components that keep the CK. So it is both necessary and sufficient to keep a CK's attributes together in some component, and given that, it is redundant to include the projections on the separate attributes. But if those CK attributes can be divided into subsets all of whose tuple combinations appear, you can decompose, but that's not needed *for 3NF*.

Comment: PS You need to give up on "specific" & semantics" & "makes sense" & "mix" & scare quotes & "information" & "independent" etc, all hopelessly vague, and say what you actually mean, in terms of relations & projections/components & tuples & joins etc. And you may find the notion of *(characteristic) predicate (of a set)* helpful. (A mapping from a situation and a tuple to a truth value; the criterion by which we put a given tuple into or leave it out of an associated relation body.) Because if two relations JOIN to a relation, the arguments' predicates AND to the result's predicate.

Comment: Eg: What does it mean for a component to not 'make sense' or to ' "mix" attributes that aren't related'? (The original relation holds the tuples whose values are related in some way--say, they are the <A,...> tuples satifying p(A,..). So a component projecting out X,... holds tuples that satisfy EXISTS X,... p(A,...)--ie, the tuples whose values are so related.)

Answer (score 2):

The last step of the 3NF normalization algorithm is needed to guarantee that the decomposition generated by the algorithm is lossless.

In fact there is a theorem that states that if a decomposition preserves the dependencies, and one of the decomposed schema is a superkey of the original relation, then the decomposition is also lossless.

The algorithm, with the previous steps, guarantees that every functional dependency is present in some of the decomposed relation. The introduction of a relation that contains a key, if no key is already present in some of the other relation, guarantees that the algorithm produces a decomposition that preserves both data and dependencies.

**Added**

Here is a simple example that shows the need of this last step. Suppose that an instance of the relation R(A, B, C, D), with A->B, C->D, (with key A,C) is:

```
R
A | B | C | D
-------------
1   2   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   2   3
```

The decomposition in R1(A,B), R2(C,D) is in third normal form but is lossy (additive). In fact, projecting that instance on the decomposition produces:

```
R1          R2
A | B       C | D
-----       -----
1   2       2   3
2   3       3   4
```

The additive property of this decomposition is clear if we perform a natural join of the decomposed relation, which produces an instance different from the original one:

```
R1 ⨝ R2 =
A | B | C | D
-------------
1   2   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   2   3
2   3   3   4
```

The situation does not change if you decompose R in R1(A,B), R2(C,D), R3(A), R4(C): in fact, recomposing it with R1 ⨝ R2 ⨝ R3 ⨝ R4 produces exactly the same relation as above with 4 rows:

```
R1          R2          R3     R4       R1 ⨝ R2 ⨝ R3 ⨝ R4 =
A | B       C | D       A      C        A | B | C | D
-----       -----       --     ---      --------------
1   2       2   3       1      2        1   2   2   3
2   3       3   4       2      3        1   2   3   4
                                        2   3   2   3
                                        2   3   3   4
```

Instead, the situation changes completely with the decomposition in R1(A,B), R2(C,D), R3(A, C). When you recompose with the natural join you obtain the original instance:

```
R1          R2           R3          R1 ⨝ R2 ⨝ R3 =
A | B       C | D        A | C       A | B | C | D
-----       -----        ------      --------------
1   2       2   3        1   2       1   2   2   3
2   3       3   4        1   3       1   2   3   4
                         2   2       2   3   2   3
```

So, in summary, in the first two cases you have a loss of information (the original instance is not obtained), while in the third case you have a 3NF **and** a lossless (nonadditive) decomposition.

Comment: Right, but I struggle to see how it is necessary to not lose information. For example, if  R=(A, B, C, D), the key is (A, C) and F = {A->B, C->D}, the algorithm would produce R1=(A,B); R2=(C,D) and R3=(A,C). The attributes in R3 are stored in the others...

Comment: If the key is AC, then storing A and C separately does not preserve the information. Suppose for instance that you have order lines, identified by order number and line number. If you have a set of order lines, and decompose them by putting separately the order number and the line number, than the information about the the actual order lines stored is lost. In fact when doing the natural join to recompose the original relation, this produces too many rows, and not the original order lines.

Comment: Would you lose information even in my previous example (where A and C are independent)?

Comment: Each FD is associated with  MVD ie binary JD. It's not clear what you mean by "independent", but 3NF only gets rid of some problematic FDs, and BCNF gets rid of all problematic FDs. However, problematic MVDs can still then remain, which 4NF is free of. Your decomposition example may happen to be lossless because it decomposes per a BCNF-problematic FD or problematic MVD not associated with a FD. So just because you see an example where a decomposition is lossless doesn't mean it's the kind the 3NF algorithm deals with. Its decompositions always introduce a table with the attributes of a FD.

Comment: And what happens with the semantics of the relation with the key?  If clientId -> customerName and date -> season, R3(clientId, date) could be linking things that may not have to do with each other. Or I am assuming something wrong?

Comment: @John I'll post an answer when I can. But it *doesn't matter*. (Like I just said:) The 3NF algorithm gets rid of certain bad FDs/JDs. If there *are* other bad  FDs/JDs, they're the kind that you get rid of by higher NF algorithms. That's no fault of the 3NF algorithm. Your confusion may be that you expect all anomalies to be removed by 3NF. 3NF still has problems. All base tables should be normalized to 5NF. The only reason they aren't is that current SQL DBMSs don't make the necessary constraints easy to express or execute. And normalization is poorly taught academically & industrially.

Comment: @John Re your first comment "The attributes in R3 are stored in the others"--that is really too vague to capture what you seem to mean, but the fact is it's not enough that we find projections/components with enough attributes; the components of a lossy aka "additive" decomposition join to a relation with all the original's tuples *plus others*. The finally added component is needed to prevent these spurious tuples. Now, if there *aren't* any spurious tuples before adding that last component it's because the original relation is subject to a problematic JD that is not addressed by 3NF.

Comment: @John, I've updated the answer to show why you have a loss of information by having separate tables for the attributes of the key.